# What property of integration over probability densities allows this?

Tags: probability, integration, bayes-theorem

Here is the concerning part of the equation that I am trying to understand dealing with the variational lower bound and Kullback-Leibler divergence.

$$
\begin{aligned}
&- \int_Z q(Z) \log \frac{p(Z|X)}{q(Z)} \\
&= -\Big( \int_Z q(Z) \log \frac{p(X,Z)}{q(Z)} - \int_Z q(Z) \log p(X) \Big)
\end{aligned}
$$

I just don't get what property of integration would give this. $p(X, Z)$ would be equal to $p(X|Z)p(Z)$ by bayes theorem, so it must be doing that somewhat in reverse, but I can't justify why that would be

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$P(Z|X)=\frac{P(Z,X)}{P(X)}=\frac{P(X,Z)}{P(X)}$ since $P(X,Z)=P(Z,X)$.

**Edit**

By the above equality, you have
$$\int_Z q(Z)\log\frac{p(Z|X)}{q(Z)}= \int_Z q(Z) \log \frac{p(X,Z)}{q(Z)p(X)} =\int_Z q(Z)\left[\log\frac{p(X,Z)}{q(Z)}-\log p(X)\right]$$

Comment: I don't see how that answers my question. I get what you said, but I don't see how it applies, can you explain more?

Comment: @deltaskelta I have edited the answer to make it clearer.

Answer (score 1):

Since:

$$\frac{p(Z \mid X)p(X)}{q(Z)}= p(X \mid Z) = \frac{p(X, Z)}{q(Z)} $$

we have:

$$log  \left ( \frac{p(Z \mid X)p(X)}{q(Z)} \right ) = log\left ( \frac{p(X, Z)}{q(Z)} \right )$$

from which, finally:

$$log\left ( \frac{p(X, Z)}{q(Z)} \right ) =  log\left ( \frac{p(Z \mid X)}{q(Z)}  \right ) + log(p(X))$$

Comment: Shouldnt your minus be a plus since $log(a*b) = log(a) + log(b)$

Comment: It absolutely should, thanks for spotting it